# Introduction Of Mitchell-Bénabou-Language

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

I'm confused about the introduction of the Mitchell-Bénabou-language in Sheaves in Geometry and Logic:

> Here are the inductive clasues which simultaneously define the terms of the language and their interpretation:
>
> - Each variable $x$ of type $X$ is a term of type $X$; its interpretation is the identity $x = 1 : X \to X$.
> - Terms $\sigma$ and $\tau$ of types $X$ and $Y$, interpreted by $\sigma : U \to X$ and $\tau : V \to Y$, yield a term $\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle$ of type $X \times Y$; its interpretation is
>   $$ \langle \sigma p, \tau q \rangle : W \to X \times Y,$$
>   where the source $W$ has evident projections $p : W \to U$ and $q : W \to V$. Here the notation $\langle \quad, \quad \rangle$ is used ambiguously, both for hte new term and for the familiar map into the product $X \times Y$.
> - Terms $\sigma : U \to X$ and $\tau : V \to X$ of the same type $X$ yield a term $\sigma = \tau$ of type $\Omega$, interpreted by
>   $$(\sigma = \tau) : W \overset{\langle \sigma p, \tau q \rangle}{\longrightarrow} X \times X \overset{\delta_X}{\longrightarrow} \Omega,$$

In the second point, why not saying $W=U\times V$? Is there a subtle difference between $W$ and $U\times V$ which I'm not seeing right now?

Comment: See how it is consistently trying to avoid that? The third bullet point does that too. This is to make later explanation less confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try to read on and see if it clarifies itself!

Comment: It doesn’t even define $W$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understand now. I didn't pay attention to the part before. They don't duplicate free variables, so $W$ is not necessarily $U\times V$ but rather the product of the types of free variables occuring in $U$ or $V$ as far as I understand.  E.g. if $U=X\times Y$ and $V=Y\times Z$ then $W=X\times Y\times Z$ and not $X\times Y^2\times Z$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that others on the site will have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes will do so!  But I rather thought about deleting the question since I think I resolved it...  Not sure if it is still useful to anybody?

Comment: In general it's not worth deleting questions -- you asked it, and other people might have a similar question in the future! Instead, if you've resolved it yourself, you should write up an answer to your own question! That way other people can also benefit from your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you've realized the broad reason for this in the comments, but I'll say a quick word about it here.

The domain of our map $\sigma : U \to X$ can be thought of as the *context of variables* in which $\sigma$ lives. For instance, the term-in-context $x : \mathbb{N}, y : \mathbb{N} \vdash (x+y) : \mathbb{N}$ is interpreted by the arrow $(+) : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Now say we have terms-in-context $x : \mathbb{N} \vdash x+1$ and $x : \mathbb{N} \vdash x+2$. Then there's two natural ways we can interpret the term $\langle x+1, x+2 \rangle : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Either, we mean

$$
x : \mathbb{N}, x' : \mathbb{N} \vdash \langle x + 1, x' + 2 \rangle : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}
$$

or we mean

$$
x : \mathbb{N} \vdash \langle x+1, x+2 \rangle : \mathbb{N}
$$

First, do you see the difference between these two terms-in-context? And second, do you see how the first is represented by an arrow $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and the second is represented by an arrow $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$? In each case the domain $W$ has natural projections $W \to \mathbb{N}$ and $W \to \mathbb{N}$, it's just that in the second case these projection maps are the same! This is *exactly* the feature that allows us to stipulate that two variables in a term are "the same", which is an incredibly useful ability to have!

I'll also mention here that while the mitchell-benabou *language* is extremely useful (read: the syntax is), its *interpretation* (read: semantics) as defined in Mac Lane and Moerdijk is often less so. Instead, there are alternative semantics defined in the coming sections (namely the kripke-joyal semantics and the special case of sheaf semantics) which are (at least in my experience) easier to work with in practice. I wish Mac Lane and Moerdijk had made it more clear that the various semantics they define are all (roughly equivalent) ways of interpreting the same language. See also the discussion [here](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/3012/mitchellbenabou-language-and-kripkejoyal-semantics/) for more information about this.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This is a great answer, and I very much agree with your comment on the semantics. I tried to compose introductions to the Kripke–Joyal semantics here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.13850, Section 2.4 (with lots of exercises); and https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00948 (short).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and for the additional ressources @IngoBlechschmidt, looking forward to dive into this and also the Kripke-Joyal semantics!